# Replace after a needle in a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, search, replace

I have a string, something like

> bbbbabbbbbccccc

Are there any way for me to replace all the letters "b" after the only one letter "a" into "c" without having to split the string, using PHP?

> bbbbacccccccccc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

odd question.

```
echo preg_replace('/a(.*)$/e', "'a'.strtr($1, 'b', 'c')", 'bbbabbbbbccccc');
```

preg_replace matches everything to the right of 'a' with regex. the e modifier in the regex evaluates the replacement string as code. the code in the replacement string uses strtr() to replace 'b's with 'c's.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three options.

First, a split.  Yes, I know you want to do it without a split.

```
$string = 'bbbbabbbbbccccc';
$parts = preg_split('/(a)/', $string, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
// Parts now looks like:
// array('bbb', 'a', 'bbbbcccc');
$parts[2] = str_replace('b', 'c', $parts[2]);
$correct_string = join('', $parts);
```

Second, a position search and a substring replacement.

```
$string = 'bbbbabbbbbccccc';
$first_a_index = strpos($string, 'a');
if($first_a_index !== false) {
// Now, grab everything from that first 'a' to the end of the string.
    $replaceable = substr($string, $first_a_index);
// Replace it.
    $replaced = str_replace('b', 'c', $replaceable );
// Now splice it back in
    $string = substr_replace($string, $replaced, $first_a_index);
}
```

Third, I was going to post a regex, but [the one dqhendricks posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698369/replace-after-a-needle-in-a-string/4698422#4698422) is just as good.

These code examples are verbose for clarity, and can be reduced to one-or-two-liners.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s = 'bbbbabbbbbccccc';
echo preg_replace('/((?:(?!\A)\G|(?<!a)a(?!a))[^b]*)b/', '$1c', $s);
```

`\G` matches the position where the previous match ended.  On the first match attempt, `\G` matches the beginning of the string like `\A`.  We don't want that, so we use `(?!\A)` to prevent it.

`(?<!a)a(?!a)` matches an `a` that's neither preceded nor followed by an `a`.  The `a` is captured in group #1 so we can plug it back into the replacement with `$1`.

This is a "pure regex" solution, meaning it does the whole job in one call to `preg_replace` and doesn't rely on embedded code and the `/e` modifier.  It's good to know in case you ever find yourself working within those constraints, but it definitely shouldn't be your first resort.